# Why my minecraft always crashed when i play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

It's like this:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// My bad.

Time: 7/22/17 1:49 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bhz.at(SourceFile:635)
    at bhz.aq(SourceFile:458)
    at bhz.a(SourceFile:404)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bhz.at(SourceFile:635)
    at bhz.aq(SourceFile:458)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bhz.a(SourceFile:404)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_141, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 48543712 bytes (46 MB) / 151007232 bytes (144 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.12
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-297) for your setup (Win 10 and a new Java installation).

Try downgrading Java to a version older than Java 8 Update 60 ([clicky](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)) or using the [native launcher](https://launcher.mojang.com/download/MinecraftInstaller.msi) as described in the bug report. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! But what java should i choose? The development or the runtime environment? Please help me, i'm a noob player

Comment: @JamesDeragon use the Runtime Environment. The other one is for developers.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have a resource pack? 
If you have, I recommend to delete it or move it out your minecraft folder by folder system.